# Read XML from stream, extract node, base64 decode it and write to file with minimum internal memory required

Tags: c#, xml, stream, base64

I've a `WebResponse.GetResponseStream` which could deliver me a string (XML file). Now I need only one node of the XML which is carrying the data (ok I would need some other nodes too). I could now save the stream as XML file. Afterwards I'd need to parse it, extract the data from the node and save it as file *again*. Then I would base64 decode this file and save the real file *again*.

For all that I want to use the minimum possible amount of internal memory (RAM). Doing everything on the fly decreases the memory very fast on bigger files and also could lead to a out-of-memory problem. In my idea described above I'd write multiple files to extract the data. Can this be done in one step so that only one file is written at all? Though the main requirement is to be as memory (RAM) efficient as possible. Perhaps only one small buffer is necessary, but no doubling or tripling of the memory is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an XMLReader

```css
            string xml = "";  //put your string input here
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xreader = XmlReader.Create(reader);
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an XmlReader is correct... but you do NOT want to load it into a 'string' to do it.  Rather, XmlReader is designed to read from a stream just fine.  Use XmlReader.Create(yourStream).